# Vertical banner with hide/show button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to show vertical banner for a bootstrap page with the `contianer` `div` which i don't want to, as it breaks the design. I thought of having vertically aligned banner to either left of right of actual content and for a specific with let us say minimum ***900px*** width,

I have designed them likes [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/6w7dvbzd/) but want to add functionality similar to one show in this [example](http://www.slidebanners.com/examples7.php)

**I want to show vertical banner on either side with hide & show button**

Updated Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/6w7dvbzd/4/

Comment: Okay, so, what's the question?

Comment: @JeremyThille, I want to show vertical banner on either side with hide & show button

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have same effect on the sample page, try this one.

```js
  $(function () {
    $( "#left-ad" ).animate({ "left": "0" }, "slow" );
  });
```

```css
#left-ad {
    position:absolute;
    left:-99px;
    position: fixed;
    width:100px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;
    margin:auto 0;
}
#sidebar {
    margin:auto 0;
    background-color:green;
    height:200px;
}
.right-ad {
    right:0;
    position: fixed;
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:red;
}
.wrapper {
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:blue;
    height:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left-ad">
    <div id="sidebar"> <a href="#"><img src="sidewall.png" alt="LEft Banner" ></a>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="right-ad"> <a href="#"><img src="wad.jpg" alt="Right Banner" style="border-width: 0px" ></a>

</div>
<div class=wrapper>//center body part</div>
```